# Problems including comdef.h

Tags: windows-phone-8

I'm trying to port some existing code to WP8 and have come across a problem.
The code i am porting uses a smart pointer thats is defined in comdef.h but for some reason when I try and include comdef.h I get the following error.

comdef.h(25): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'olectl.h'

I understand what the error means and it seems there is no trace of "olectl.h" in the WP8 SDK include paths on my machine. Is anyone else having this problem, I've tried "repairing" my installation of "Visual studio 2012 Express for Windows Phone"

I have found some code that appears to include comdef.h and has gotten around the missing macro problem the link at the end of this post is talking about by not using the macro at all and explicitly using the code that the macro would expand to.
(Here is the code that does what I want to: https://devel.nuclex.org/framework/browser/graphics/Nuclex.Graphics.Native/trunk/Source/Rasterization/Direct3D11/Direct3D11Api.h?rev=1782)

Has anyone else experienced this, or could someone with the SDK installed try including comdef.h somewhere to see if it works for them.

The missing macro link:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/751127/com-smartptr-typedef-causes-errors-when-used-in-winrt-build

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I see this too, so it appears  this is "by-design".

Basically if the API isn't listed [on MSDN in the list of supported COM/Win32 APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207198%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), then it isn't a supported API on Windows Phone 8. It looks like only the `combaseapi.h` header is supported.

`_com_ptr_t<T>` and it's friends aren't on the list...